# Add JAR files to a project in Eclipse using Maven

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am trying to add certain JAR files, related to the Spring Framework, required for a project using Maven.

**`Project Name: Spring`**

[image: Project Name: Spring]

Is it possible to do this using Maven?

The dependency is as follows:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aspects -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: First you have not imported the project as Maven project into Eclipse furthermore the lib directory contains jar's which should not be the case cause that should be handled by Maven...

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to add JAR files manually. Maven will do it for you. You just need to define dependency in `pom.xml`.

Following is an example `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
    http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <groupId>com.spring.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.spring.test</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>3.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should import the project as a **Maven project**. If it is not a Maven project you can **convert** it using Eclipse.

And then you should put your dependency as one of the `dependencies` in the **pom.xml** of the project like this:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aspects -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```